# how to execute the interactive commands programmatically in django-tenants

Tags: django

in my terminal i can execute 
1)first command

```
python manage.py tenant_command rebuild_index
```

2)second command.

the terminal will ask which schema shall i execute. for that  i enter my schema name called xxx

```
Enter Tenant Schema ('?' to list schemas): xxx
```

3)3rd command i need to enter y/n option extra in terminal

then i Entered Enter

This is working fine so how to achieve this in pragmatically using management call_command pragmatically in django

```
 management.call_command('python manage.py tenant_command rebuild_index', 'xxx')
```

but it giving error like

```
File "/home/hi/venv/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 94, in call_command
    raise CommandError("Unknown command: %r" % name)
CommandError: Unknown command: 'python manage.py tenant_command rebuild_index'
```

so please any body tell me is it possible to achieve this kind of interactive terminal commands to run pragmatically in django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by running it in a periodic task instead of running manual rebuild index commands everytime. See code below...

```
from django.core import management

def hi():
     management.call_command('rebuild_index',schema_name="xxx",interactive=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the schema name as a keyword argument called `schema_name` so that the `tenant_command` does not prompt. You also do not need to pass `python manage.py`.

The syntax you want is:

```
from django.core import management

management.call_command('tenant_command', 'rebuild_index', schema_name='xxx')
```

Comment: 3rd command i need to enter y/n option extra so how to do interminal

Comment: It sounds as though the y/n prompt is coming from the wrapped `rebuild_index` command. You'd need to look at that command to see whether you can run it non-interactively (e.g. by specifying `-y` or `-n` or whatever it requires) and then pass that argument to `call_command`.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`call_command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) only needs the command name, like this:

```
management.call_command('tenant_command', 'rebuild_index')
```

Try that and see if that works. Read the docs I linked as well, there are a few examples.

Comment: nothing working,its error unrecognised arguments:rebuild_index...............error